# Webkit Property Placement: CSS

Tags: css, webkit, multiple-browsers

```
.slideOutUp.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.slideOutUp.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            transform: translateY(-100%); 
}
```

This is the css property I want to place inside an id called #headpanel.

I have tried many permutations and combinations but the effects just won't take place. Help?

Comment: A little hard to diagnose without seeing more. If possible, can you create a fiddle to replicate the issue? Without seeing it, is the element you're trying to translate an inline displayed element?

Comment: Ok, so, I have a certain class which specifies certain properties(and their values). This is perfect to run globally. However, for one particular ID I need that class to have different values of those properties. I cannot specify those property-value pairs explicitly for that ID. I must make them change through the class. How do I achieve that?

Can't create fiddle. It would require hundreds of lines of angularJS code. Can you help?